# IEnumreable dynamic and lambda

Tags: c#, dynamic, ienumerable

I would like to use a lambda expression on a `IEnumerable<dynamic>` type, howerver im getting the following error on attributes and coordinates where im using a new lambda expression:

`Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type`.

Here is my code

```
public static object returnFullSelectWithCoordinates(IEnumerable<dynamic> q)
        {
            return q.Select(b => new
            {
                route_id = b.b.route_id,
                name = b.b.name,
                description = b.b.description,
                attributes = b.b.route_attributes.Select(c => c.route_attribute_types.attribute_name),
                coordinates = b.b.coordinates.Select(c => new coordinateToSend { sequence = c.sequence, lat = c.position.Latitude, lon = c.position.Longitude })

            });
```

Is there any workaround to make my method work?

Comment: A `dynamic` as a parameter of a public method doesn't look like a good idea IMO

Comment: This is just a test method, i'm trying to figure out how i can make "templates" for Select on LINQ queries of anonymous types.

Comment: The error message is telling you how to make it work. **Cast the lambda to a delegate or expression tree type**.

Answer (score 0):

Since `Select<>` is an extension method, it won't work on dynamic types.

You can get the same result by using `Enumerable.Select<>`.

Try this query:

```
Enumerable.Select(q,(Func<dynamic,dynamic>)(b => new
        {
            route_id = b.b.route_id,
            name = b.b.name,
            description = b.b.description,
            attributes = b.b.route_attributes.Select(c => c.route_attribute_types.attribute_name),
            coordinates = b.b.coordinates.Select(c => new coordinateToSend { sequence = c.sequence, lat = c.position.Latitude, lon = c.position.Longitude })

        });
```