# c# predefine LINQ select

Tags: c#, linq, select

I would like to apply the same `SELECT` to an amount of `queries`, how do i do this? I'm looking to make some kind of template i'm guessing?

```
var query = (from b in db.routes select new 
{ name = b.name,
age = b.age});
```

I would like to predefine name=b.name and age = b.age.

Thanks

Comment: Please show your code !! so that other can help you

Comment: You really need to be more specific to get an answer.

Comment: Do all of the queries deal with the same source type?

Comment: Please don't create duplicates of your own question. This one has even *less* information than the previous one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tricky bit with your example is that you're using an anonymous type - which means you can't write a method (you can't declare the return type) and you can't assign a lambda expression to a local variable (you need to be able specify a type to convert the lambda expression to).

You *also* can't just use type inference to return something from a generic method - as you wouldn't be able to specify just the input type. However, you can use type inference with a generic class:

```
public static class Functions<T>
{
    public static Func<T, TResult> Create<TResult>(Func<T, TResult> func)
    {
        return func;
    }
}
```

Then you can write:

```
var projection = Functions<Route>.Create(r => new { r.name, r.age });

var query = db.routes
              .Select(projection)
              ...;
```

But if you really want to use the same projection in multiple places, you should consider creating a named result type instead - at which point you *can* use any of the other options, including a conversion method.

Comment: I created method(IEnumerable<dynamic> x), that one accepts the query as anonymous type and i can do a x.Select, however i can't use any lambda expressions inside of that, i keep getting "Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type"

Comment: @user2049921: I could be wrong, but it sounds like you might be a little out of your depth. I would *strongly* advise steering clear of dynamic typing until you're *really* comfortable with how C# works in general.

Comment: It's way out of my depth actually, however it's a part of a project i really would like to solve, sadly no time to rewrite a big part of the code which is very needed.

Comment: @user2049921: Writing code you don't really understand will *cost* you time, certainly in the long term and quite possibly in the short term too.

Comment: I could make types for all my queries to get rid of the anonymous type problem, i will probably have to do that. However i would like to know if it's possible to make this whole IEnumreable<dynamic> and lambda expression to work?

Comment: @user2049921: You'd have to give a much more concrete example of what you're trying, ideally in a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a method with an `IEnumerable<SomeBaseClassOrInterfacee>` argument.
then you can do your select against given argument within the method.

```
public class Generic
{
    protected Generic(string name, int age)
    {
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public int Age { get; private set; }
}

public class Human : Generic 
{
    public Human(string name, string surname, int age) : base(name, age)
    {
        Surname = surname;
    }

    public string Surname { get; private set; }
}

public class Pet : Generic
{
    public Pet(string name, int registrationCode, int age)
        : base(name, age)
    {
        RegistrationCode = registrationCode;
    }

    public int RegistrationCode { get; private set; }
}


static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IEnumerable<Pet> pets = new List<Pet>();
    IEnumerable<Human> palls = new List<Human>();

    var resPets = SelectAgeGreaterThen10<Pet>(from p in pets where p.Name.StartsWith("A") select p);
    var resHumans = SelectAgeGreaterThen10<Human>(from p in palls where p.Name.StartsWith("B") select p);

}

private static IEnumerable<T> SelectAgeGreaterThen10<T>(IEnumerable<Generic> source) where T : Generic
{
    return from s in source where s.Age > 10 select (T)s;
}
```

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Comment: The problem is that i'm using the same SELECT for many queries, if i want to update my select i only want to change the code at one place, like a template. Even if i do an interface for my select i still have to set the data in the select.

Answer (score 0):

How's this look:

```
class NameAndAge
{
    public String Name;
    public Int32 Age;
}

class Whatever
{
    public IEnumerable<NameAndAge> GetNameAndAges(IEnumerable<dynamic> enumerable)
    {
         return from b in enumerable select new NameAndAge { Name = b.name,
                                                             Age = b.age};
    } 
}
```

You'll probably want to replace `dynamic` in the argument type with whatever the type of the elements in `db.routes` are.

Comment: Looks a lot like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15385260/ienumreable-dynamic-and-lambda) actually. =)

Comment: That's what im doing right now, however i would like to use an lambda expression inside of that Select, i don't know how to solve ""Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type"

Comment: Cast it to a delegate or expression tree?  Or you could do what I suggested in the answer, and change `dynamic` to the real type.